# FileUtils not accessible in androidx

Tags: android, androidx

I recently migrated my project to androidx and now I can't find the FileUtils class.

Here is my build.gradle file.

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc02"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc02"
```

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I have not.